# Grafana - Pass dashboard variable to Alert

Tags: variables, grafana, alert

In a Dashboard, we have used the following variables:

[image]

For a alert, we would like to pass in the "resource" variable to the notifications.

I tried adding "$resource" in the AlertValues, changing from:

[image]

to

[image]

but that changes my alert from:

[image]

to

[image]

How can we refer to the variables in the alerts?

Thanks!

Comment: IIUC, you can't do this, as alerts are independent from variables, and thus cannot be passed into template.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!


Lets say if I have 10 Postgres SQL Servers I would like to monitor, could I use 1 alert rule for monitoring them, or would it require 1 alert rule per server / per object I would like to monitor?

Or can this be set up in some dynamic way?